# How to snyc data refresh between C# apps at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, synchronization

I have a C# program that calls a SQL database.
I want to duplicate this program 10 times and have all programs call the SQL database at the same time.  How would this be done?

I am pulling data on a timer/loop. For example, if program A is executed before program B, the refresh times will differ. Is there a way to sync this refresh?

Comment: Hello, have you considered a web application?

Comment: how accurately do you require this synchronisation? "The same time" has  a number of meanings. The same second? The same tick? If your program is running on more than one machine can you synchronize those clocks?

Comment: unfortunately it has to be an application. Not web this time around.  Also, it needs to be with in seconds between each apps sync. So pretty accurate.

Comment: So use the Database Time to synchronize every application time. So you can raise the database call on multiples of 10 seconds. Example:  
10:10  
10:20  
10:30  
....

Comment: If you make the refresh time small enough then it will seem like they are all in sync.  For instance if you refresh every second then at most any app will be a second off the other one.  Most users would not notice that.  However that is ALOT of calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to have a man in the middle. I mean, you need to provide a service between your desktop clients and the DB. That service will contain the update timer.

Now, every X seconds you ping that service to seek if the update time has changed. And every time that a client call for data, well, you update the timer on the service. So suppose there rest 3 minutes to update, every client knows that, but then your program A does something that alter that timer, well then, when others ping the service will note that and change it's internal update timers also.

Comment: Sounds possible, but I need the client apps to refresh at the same time. One day maybe 3 apps are turned on and hit this service. Another day maybe all 10 apps are on, and ping the service. I am not sure how to trigger all client apps to update at once.

Comment: What do you mean by trigging the client app att once?

Comment: @user999690 Then implement it backwards. You'll need the Apps to be online and make your service to PUSH notify your clients (that'll occur at the same time). Search for that, how to implement for PUSH notification.

Comment: Randolf: that makes sense. Will I have to worry about firewalls and computers on other networks interfering?

Comment: @user999690 Firewalls are always a pain in the.. for devs!

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the simplest solution is to just make the calls to the DB at every full minute. All the clients have the same Time servers, so there clock should be in sync?

Or you can have a server application that all the clients connect to thru socket, or pulling data thru a simple HTTP request. When they get the "update command" they simply query the database.

Or you make a server application that querys the database and cache the data. And the clients only query the cache. Simple to implement with WCF